# Python: how make class, inherited from list, with access to first element?

Tags: python, class

In Python I would like to make class *MyList* and inherit from *list*. Besides I would like to make attribute *first*, which is equal to first element of list.
For example, for such code

```
l = MyList([0, 1, 2])
print (l.first)
l.first = 3
print (l)
```

I would like to see

```
0
[3, 1, 2]
```

I write

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, input_list):
        self.first = input_list[0]

my_list = MyList([0, 1, 2])
print (my_list)
print (my_list.first)
```

and get

```
[]
0
```

Why my_list is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a call to the `super` class, and for `first` to work as expected I'd recommend a `property`:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, input_list):
        super(MyList, self).__init__(input_list)
        self.first = input_list[0]

    @property
    def first(self):
        return self[0]

    @first.setter
    def first(self, value):
        self[0] = value
```

Now calling:

```
my_list = MyList([0, 1, 2])
print (my_list)
print (my_list.first)
my_list.first = 12
print (my_list)
print (my_list.first)
```

gives:

```
[0, 1, 2]
0
[12, 1, 2]
12
```

Comment: Once first is a property, you don't need to override init anymore (see my answer)

Comment: If an instance `ml` of `MyList` is intialized with an empty list, `print(ml.first)` or `ml.first = 5` will throw an IndexError.

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling list's `__init__` in your `__init__`.

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, input_list):
        super(MyList, self).__init__(input_list)
        self.first = input_list[0]
```

Also, rather than affecting first at init, you should use a [property](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#property) so as to return the first value even when the values of the list have been changed after initialization.

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, input_list):
        super(MyList, self).__init__(input_list)

    @property
    def first(self):
        # TODO: catch empty list exception
        return self[0]
```

in which case you wouldn't even have to override self, so it simplifies as

```
class MyList(list):

    @property
    def first(self):
        # TODO: catch empty list exception
        return self[0]
```

Comment: I think this is only one part of OP's problem.  OP is also setting an attribute, rather that setting items to the list. edit: actually, I see what you mean, you'll pass the list to `list`'s init.

Comment: @Gator_Python: exactly. I'm showing this on educational purpose as it is a common pattern (override + call to super), but in practice, you'd use a property and you wouldn't need to override init in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Define `first` as a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#property) rather than a simple attribute.

```
class MyList(list):
    @property
    def first(self):
        return self[0]

    @first.setter
    def first(self, val):
        self[0] = val
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> lst = MyList([0, 1, 2])
>>> lst.first
0
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2]
>>> lst.first = 100
>>> lst
[100, 1, 2]
```

Comment: If an instance `ml` of `MyList` is intialized with an empty list, `print(ml.first)` or `ml.first = 5` will throw an IndexError.

Comment: @S.deMelo Yeah, that's something OP can handle if they want to. Otherwise it would raise an appropriate error.